# How to find delta from two tables of two different schema

Tags: mysql, sql

How to find delta from two tables of two different schema.

I have a two different schema and each have table.

Lets say PersonInfo and DeptInfo.

In PersonInfo I have a table called person. this is what table look like

```
id|PersonName|Salary|DeptCode
```

In same way I have department Table in DeptInfo.

```
id|DeptCode|DeptName|DeptBranch
```

Now i want to get all the delta value from person Table by using DeptCode.

But proble here is these are two different table. when i am using this

```
use  PersonInfo;
```

in my sql bench i am loosing hold of DeptInfo.

Now two question how make both accessable in workbench and second how to find delta from these two tables of two different schema.

Here is the data :

```
(0,Name1,10000,100)
(1,Name2,20000,200)
(2,Name3,30000,100)
(3,Name4,40000,300)


(0,100,"Marketing","Business"),
(1,200,"Marketing","Business"),
(2,100,"Technical","Engineering")
```

here is personinfo and deptinfo data. so we can see that there is no deptCode of 300 so that is the delta here. o/p will be like

```
(3,Name4,40000,300)
```

Comment: Can you please help me to write query about this.

Comment: *i want to get all the delta value* - what is this? Departments without employees? person without department? something else? explain in details, or show on some data example...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how to ... from these two tables of two different schema.

Specify complete table names, including database/schema name, in the query. Not `... FROM person AS p, ...` but `... FROM PersonInfo.person AS p, ...`.

I.e.

```
SELECT p.PersonName,
       p.Salary,
       d.DeptName,
       d.DeptBranch
FROM PersonInfo.person AS p
JOIN DeptInfo.department AS d USING (DeptCode)
```

In such case it doesn't matter what DB is set as current with `USE`.

Comment: ya this is working fine I have update the data here. I have one quick question here. Will this same work for different sql server as well.

Comment: @David *Will this same work for different sql server* Depends on DBMS (and sometimes on the version). In most DBMSs it will work.